# React.js - Cannot import simple variable from one file into another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't figure out how to import a extremely simple variable from one file into another (new to react). I have the main App.js where line 3 appears to be the problem:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import NavMenu from "./components/nav-menu";
import navLinks from "/components/nav-links";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      navLinks: navLinks
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <NavMenu navLinks={this.state.navLinks} />
      </div>
    );
  } 
}
```

Which just imports (or should import) the `navLinks` variable from this `nav-links.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';

export const navLinks = [
    {
      name: "home",
      href: "/"
    },
    {
      name: "subs",
      href: "/subs"
    }
  ];
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of where I'm going wrong here? Also, it's being used to just render a navigation menu (so links within a tags) - is this generally the right way to go about adding nav links?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j42gep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this:

```
export const navLinks = [
    {
      name: "home",
      href: "/"
    },
    {
      name: "subs",
      href: "/subs"
    }
  ];
```

then you are importing it wrong. Then do this:

```
import {navLinks} from "./components/nav-links";
```

**Note** this: `./components/nav-links` you forgot `./` in import statement

If you dont want to use `{}` the add default statement in your export like this:

```
const navLinks = [
    {
      name: "home",
      href: "/"
    },
    {
      name: "subs",
      href: "/subs"
    }
  ];

  export default navLinks;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing to export the nav links as default :

```
import React from 'react';

 const navLinks = [
    {
      name: "home",
      href: "/"
    },
    {
      name: "subs",
      href: "/subs"
    }
  ];

  export default navLinks;
```

and add dot `.` in `import navLinks from "./components/nav-links";`

Comment: still not working with this error: Module not found: You attempted to import /components/nav-links which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: you're missing also `.` in `import navLinks from "./components/nav-links";`